# How to get rid of namespace.Classname on call of display()?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get rid of `practise.AcademicProgram` in the output when the `display()` is called for an object initialized by the parameterized constructor. In my code below this occurs when `s2.Display();` is executed.

Below is my working code for the same:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace practise
{
    public class AcademicProgram 
    {
        //Memnber variables
        private int programCode;
        private string programName;
        private int programCredits;

        //Properties for reading and writting the values of private fields
        public int ProgramCode { get => programCode; set => programCode = value; }
        public string ProgramName { get => programName; set => programName = value; }
        public int ProgramCredits { get => programCredits; set => programCredits = value; }

        //Default Constructor
        public AcademicProgram()
        {
        }

        //Parameterized Constructor
        public AcademicProgram (int programCode, string programName, int programCredits)
        {
            this.programCode = programCode;
            this.programName = programName;
            this.programCredits = programCredits;
        }

        public void DisplayResults()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program Code: {0}\nProgram Name: {1}\nProgram Credits: {2}\n", programCode, programName, programCredits);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

    public class Instructor
    {
        //Member variables
        public string forename;
        public string surname;
        public int identificationNumber;
        public AcademicProgram  academicProgram;

        //Default Constructor
        public Instructor()
        {
            this.forename = string.Empty;
            this.surname = string.Empty;
            this.identificationNumber = 0;
            this.academicProgram = null;
        }

        //Parameterized Constructor
        public Instructor(string forename, string surname, int identificationNumber, AcademicProgram  academicProgram)
        {
            this.forename = forename;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.identificationNumber = identificationNumber;
            this.academicProgram = academicProgram;
        }

        // Member Function to display values of member variables on Console.
        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.forename + ", " + this.surname + ", " + this.identificationNumber + ", " + this.academicProgram);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        //Driver function
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiating object to call non-static member method
            Instructor p = new Instructor();
            p.Go();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //Non-static Member function
        public void Go()
        {

            //Instantiating object without passing any values on runtime.
            Instructor s = new Instructor();

            //Instantiating object of AcademicProgram  class without passing any values on runtime.
            AcademicProgram  progName = new AcademicProgram ();

            //Set the values of fields using properties
            progName.ProgramCode = 8230;
            progName.ProgramName = "Systems Development: Cocnepts and Analysis";
            progName.ProgramCredits = 4;


            // Instantiating object while providing values on runtime.
            Instructor s2 = new Instructor("Eddie ", "Jessup", 2394589, progName);

            //Call to display method 
            s.Display();
            s2.Display(); 
            progName.DisplayResults();
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives an output shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j85d1.png)

Comment: AcademicProgram does now override ToString.

Comment: Just to add to the comment of @fredrik: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

Comment: You mean I should have an override method for console.writeline in AcademicProgram class ? @fredrik

Comment: Either that or explicitly select the variables in AcademicProgram you want to print in the WriteLine. Now you give it the entire instance, which will call ToString on the instance

Answer (score 1):

Aside from override [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method), I was able to fix it by a simple fix in `display()` of Instructor class as below:

```
public void Display()
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.forename + ", " + this.surname + ", " + this.identificationNumber + ", " + this.academicProgram.ProgramCode + ", " + this.academicProgram.ProgramName + ", " + this.academicProgram.ProgramCredits);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```